# DataWeave - Transformer Mule error "There is no variable named 'message'"

Tags: mule, dataweave

How to display **Outbound properties** in mule via the DataWeave transformer?

I tried this:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
{
   test_property: message.outboundProperties.testProperty
}
```

but I get this error: `There is no variable named 'message'`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

invoke directly without using 'message' as shown below

```
test_property: outboundProperties.testProperty
```

or else define a flow variable and use it as below

```
flowvar1: flowVars.flowvar1
```